# Determinant; Matrix theory

Tags: matrices

Please I encountered these while trying to solve a Vandermonde's matrix problem:- In general, if two rows of a matrix become equal for x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>j</sub>, their difference is usually divisible by x<sub>i</sub> − x<sub>j</sub>, and this observation often speeds the evaluation of determinants(I think the author is talking about determinants in general though, not just Vandermonde's matrix)

If x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>j</sub>, that means x<sub>i</sub> − x<sub>j</sub> = 0, right? So what do they mean by their difference is usually divisible by x<sub>i</sub> − x<sub>j</sub>.

Is there something am not seeing

Please can someone be of help

Cheers

Comment: What does " two rows become equal **for** $\;x_i=x_j\;$" mean? What are $\;x_i,\,x_j\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio. Thanks for your reply. Don't know, which is why I don't understand the statement. These was encountered while trying to explain the proof of the determinant of a Vandermonde's matrix. The entries of a vandermonde's matrix are x<sup>i</sup><sub>j</sub>.

Comment: @DonAntonio. The full part:- The remaining part of the explanation:- Alternative proof, using “higher” mathematics: The determinant is a polynomial in the variables x1, ..., xn of total degree 1 + 2 +· · ·+ n. It vanishes if xj = 0 or if xi = xj( i < j), and the coefficient of is + 1. These facts characterize its value. In general, if two rows of a matrix become equal for xi = xj, their difference is usually divisible by xi − xj, and this observation often speeds the evaluation of determinants.

Comment: Then it could be you wanted to say that "two rows become the same, which means row $\;i\;:\;\;(x_{i1}\;x_{i2}\;\ldots\;x_{in})\;$ equals row $\;j\;:\;\;(x_{j1}\;x_{j2}\;\ldots\;x_{jn})\;$ ...", but then, of course, the determinant equals zero. As it is the question doesn't seem to make much sense.